# adding objects to an ArrayList using an abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, abstract-class

I'm trying to add animal objects to a pet ArrayList using an accept method but I am getting an error saying cannot find symbol.  I've been over it a bunch of times and am just not seeing it.

Thanks for your help.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shelter2 implements AnimalShelter {
    private ArrayList<Animal2> pet;
    private int Id;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Shelter2() {
        pet = new ArrayList<Animal2>();
        SimpleDateFormat DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date now = new Date();
        String today = DateFormat.format(now).toString();

        // pet.add(new Cat("Snow White", "Domestic Short Hair", "White", "F",
        // "01-01-2012", null));
        // pet.add(new Dog("Buster", "Beagle", "Brown/White/Black", "male",
        // "12-25-2011", null));
        // pet.add(new Reptile("Jack", "Lizard", "01-31-2012", null));

    }

    public String allAnimals() {
        String str = "";
        for (Animal2 p : pet) {
            str = str + p + "\n\n";
        }
        return str;
    }

    public String available() {
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < pet.size(); i++) {
            Animal2 p = pet.get(i);
            if (p.getAdoptedDate() == null) {
                str = str + p + "\n\n";
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    public String adopted() {
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < pet.size(); i++) {
            Animal2 p = pet.get(i);
            if (p.getAdoptedDate() != null) {
                str = str + p + "\n\n";
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    public boolean adopt(int id) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean accept(Animal2 pet) {
        String type = null;

        System.out.println("What type of animal? (Cat, Dog, Reptile)");
        type = in.next();

        if (type == "Cat") {
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            String name = in.next();
            System.out.println("Enter description: ");
            String desc = in.next();
            System.out.println("Enter color: ");
            String color = in.next();
            System.out.println("Enter sex: ");
            String sex = in.next();
            pet.add(new Cat(name, desc, color, sex, null, null));
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

---

```
public abstract class Animal2 {
    public String name;
    public String arrivalDate;
    public String adoptedDate;

    public String getName() {
        return new String(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getArrivalDate() {
        return new String(arrivalDate);
    }

    public void setArrivalDate(String arrivalDate) {
        this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
    }

    public String getAdoptedDate() {
        return adoptedDate;
    }

    public void setAdoptedDate(String adoptedDate) {
        this.adoptedDate = adoptedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nName: " + name + "\nArrival Date: " + arrivalDate
                + "\nAdopted Date: " + adoptedDate;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal2 {
    String desc;
    String color;
    String sex;
    char s;

    Cat(String name, String desc, String color, String sex, String arrivalDate,
            String adoptedDate) {
        super.setName(name);
        super.setArrivalDate(arrivalDate);
        super.setAdoptedDate(adoptedDate);
        setDesc(desc);
        setColor(color);
        setSex(sex);
        char s = ' ';
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        s = sex.toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        if ((s == 'f') || (s == 'm')) {
            this.sex = sex;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Illegal value for Cat sex field - " + sex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (s == 'f') {
            sex = "Female";
        } else if (s == 'm') {
            sex = "Male";
        } else {
            sex = null;
        }

        return "\nCat: " + super.toString() + "\nDescription: " + desc
                + "\nColor: " + color + "\nSex: " + sex;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal2 {
    String bred;
    String color;
    String sex;
    char s;

    Dog(String name, String bred, String color, String sex, String arrivalDate,
            String adoptedDate) {
        super.setName(name);
        super.setArrivalDate(arrivalDate);
        super.setAdoptedDate(adoptedDate);
        setBred(bred);
        setColor(color);
        setSex(sex);
        char s = ' ';
    }

    public String getBred() {
        return bred;
    }

    public void setBred(String bred) {
        this.bred = bred;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        s = sex.toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        if ((s == 'f') || (s == 'm')) {
            this.sex = sex;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Illegal value for Dog sex field - " + sex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (s == 'f') {
            sex = "Female";
        } else if (s == 'm') {
            sex = "Male";
        } else {
            sex = null;
        }

        return "Dog: " + super.toString() + "\nBred: " + bred + "\nColor: "
                + color + "\nSex: " + sex;
    }
}

class Reptile extends Animal2 {
    String type;

    Reptile(String name, String type, String arrivalDate, String adoptedDate) {
        super.setName(name);
        super.setArrivalDate(arrivalDate);
        super.setAdoptedDate(adoptedDate);
        setType(type);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Reptile: " + super.toString() + "\nType: " + type;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Cannot find symbol", are you talking about a syntax error?? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: I second the request for the lines causing this error, else how can we help you? Also, don't compare Strings with `==`, but instead use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that this line is giving you the error:

```
pet.add(new Cat(name, desc, color, sex, null, null));
```

You're getting this error because `pet`, within the scope of your `accept` method, is an `Animal2`. If you want to reference the field named `pet`, try:

```
this.pet.add(new Cat(name, desc, color, sex, null, null));
```

Also, in your `Dog` and `Cat` classes, you are not setting `s`. You are creating a new variable `s` and setting it to `' '` (`char s = ' ';`). I'm not sure how that will affect your project, but you probably aren't intending to do it.